# Getting error on azure deployment for staging environment

Tags: azure, azure-deployment

I am trying to deploy my hosted service on staging with RDC configuration, 
But it giving following error:

Error Creating New Deployment
Error creating deployment for hosted service 'XXXXXXXX'
An Internal Server Error

occurred. Please retry your last operation at a later date.

An Internal Server Error occurred. Please retry your last

operation at a later date.

Dr. Watson Diagnostic ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
Subscription ID: XXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX
Time started: 11/26/2012 9:55:06 AM UTC
Time completed: 11/26/2012 9:55:37 AM UTC
Duration: 0:00:31.214

Without RDC configuration is successfully deploying but not when I keep RDC settings
in serviceconfiguration.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned the deployment fails only when RDC settings are enabled, you will have to upload the PFX certificate first otherwise deployment will fail. have you uploaded the Certificate PFX to your Windows Azure Service already? Deploying from VS did return the proper error message so you should some kind of message and if you keep seeing "Internal Server Error" you may need to contact support to find out the actual issue.

There is another way you can find out what is going wrong. When you create any kind of operation with Windows Azure Services (any kind) an Operation ID is generation and this Operation ID helps us to determine what was the problem with your request.

First log into your Windows Azure Management Portal and go to "Settings -> Operation Log". There you can select proper time frame when you tried deploying the service and collect the operation log which shows the deployment was failed similar to as below:

[image]

Once you have Operation ID available you can provide here and I can take a look what could be wrong or open a support ticket here and you will get some help.

Opening a ticket with Microsoft Support:
[image]

Comment: thanks Avkash for the reply.. this issue is resolved when i tried to upload multiple time. I did not identified the issue cause.